# toString method on Linked List implementation not working in js

Tags: javascript

I'm working through Cracking the Coding Interview and I thought I'd implement all the data structures in JS 5.  Can anyone explain to me why my toString method isn't working?

Thanks!

```js
    function Node(data) {
     this.next = null;
      this.data = data;
    }
    
    Node.prototype.appendToTail = function(data) {
     var end = new Node(data);
      var n = this;
      while (n.next != null) {
       n = n.next;
      }
      n.next = end;
    }
    
    Node.prototype.toString = function(head) {
     
     console.log(head)
    
     if (head == null) {
       return ""
      } else {
       return head.data.toString() + "-> " + head.next.toString();
      }
     
    }
    
    var ll = new Node(1);
    ll.appendToTail(3);
    ll.appendToTail(4);
    
    console.log(ll.toString())
```

Comment: "Isn't working"... what output do you expect it to give, what output are you getting instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Node(data) {
    this.next = null;
  this.data = data;
}

Node.prototype.appendToTail = function(data) {
  var end = new Node(data);
  var n = this;
  while (n.next != null) {
    n = n.next;
  }
  n.next = end;
};

Node.prototype.toString = function() {
    var returnValue = String(this.data);
    if (this.next) {
        returnValue = returnValue + "-> " + String(this.next); 
    }
    return returnValue;
};

var ll = new Node(1);
ll.appendToTail(3);
ll.appendToTail(4);

console.log(String(ll))
```

or avoid this kind of problems completly and do not use prototype, class, this, call, etc

Answer (score 1):

Your `toString` function takes an argument, but you're not passing it when you call `toString`.

If you want to access the node, you should use `this`, instead of passing in a value

```
Node.prototype.toString = function() {
   var result = this.data.toString();
   if (this.next) {
     result += "-> " + this.next.toString();
   }
   return result;
}
```